# Repair garage door chain

Tags: garage

My Genie garage door chain is broken. (There is a related issue at [issue).](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/112979/how-to-replace-a-chain-pulley-for-garage-door/112990?noredirect=1#comment173675_112990)

See the images.
[image: 2]

Also

[image: 3]

What I want is to connect two sections together via a rivet. But I don't know if the theory right?

Comment: call a garage door repair shop. Give them the name and model of the opener and they can supply a master link to join the 2 halves

Comment: @d.george. I just want to buy it online. But I don't know the English name.

Comment: It's called a "master link". It looks as if yours fell out. Look around on the floor. It may be there.   It will have 3 pieces the link, the cap,  the clip.

Comment: @d.george. Thanks. I can't find it around; I will by it online. I am not sure whether I need to connect it on the floor then put the chain in place; or place it first then connect it in the sky.

Comment: You  usually connect it in place. There is a way to loosen the chain tension, (get the instructions), install the master link, then re-tension the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes what you are looking for is a "Master Link" - they are available from places like Grainger, ACE hardware, Home Depot, Bicycle Shops, even amazon.

I looked at your pic - enlarged it - and noticed you had a Genie Pro - I did a search for the following. 
The prices though might break your candy machine money..so you will need to skip the soda and snickers bar for a day.
Somewhere under $4.00  ..

*Genie Pro Chain Master Link*

[Moving Up Garage Door Company.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007RFHJ3M)

[Garage Door Supply Company](http://store.garagedoorsupplyco.com/20060AS-Genie-Chain-Drive-Master-Link_p_313.html?gclid=CNLytOnNvtMCFdgUgQodPXIJuA)

Comment: Chains come in different sizes so unless you are specifically ordering for your make/model then you should bring your chain in to match up the link size.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose - yes they do have different sizes - from my recollection there is generally a number stamped on them somewhere (can't remember) as it has been years since I dealt with chain on a routine basis . However the OP has his model name and model number - see the ops picture (the links I posted are for that Model) , the two companies above deal in garage doors - so they should know exactly what the op needs based on his model.

Comment: @Ken, I posted another [thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/113855/the-garage-door-drive-chain-sprocket-wont-move) about the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Using a linker as suggested above will work fine, but they're quite tricky and you have to get the right size.

Another option is a **chain tool**

It will just pop out/in the rivet.
You'll be able to just remove the bad link and join the chain back up. 
[[image: chain tool]

It's quicker and easier to use and covers you for future repairs. You should be able to get one in any bike shop.

Comment: that is great to share the picture of the chain tool - I use a punch and a nut on the base side along with a hammer - it was faster - not as elegant. Your posting should help him in sizing his chain if he needs to add or remove chain to get the right size. props.

Answer (score -1):

Garage door chains look just like bicycle chain. So I would expect that you could use connection links and splice blocks that look like those used for bicycles.